# What metadata is stored on a datanode in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

While reading about the metadata that is stored on datanodes in HDFS.I came through these options but not sure whether all are correct or some or correct.

1. It stores a file with the checksum of the blocks that it stored.
2. It stores the version of the hadoop used for creating the blocks and
   the namespaceid.
3. It stores information about the other blocks in the same namespace.

What is the correct answer.?

Answer (score 2):

As per definitive guide:

HDFS blocks are stored in files with a blk_ prefix; they consist of the raw bytes of a portion of the file being stored. Each block has an associated metadata file with a .meta suffix. It is made up of a header with version and type information, followed by a series of checksums for sections of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to give an answer. But will be useful for some one.

Option 1 is correct.

```
It stores a file with the checksum of the blocks that it stored.
```

The .meta file in datanode will contain the checksum information for taht block which would be cross-checked when a client reads that block from datanode, if the checksum is not matched it throws an error.