# How does namenode query block information from datanode?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I can query information about how my files (stored in HDFS) are stored in blocks via `hdfs fsck / -files -blocks`.

As I understand, the namenode does not store information about the location of the blocks of each file and instead loads that information from the datanodes. Reference - [Why datanode sends the block location information to namenode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34230992/4647107)

So if the namenode is querying the information from the datanodes, the namenode should know where the datanodes metadata is located. Which would mean that there technically could be a pathway from -

```
 NameNode FSImage -> DataNodes metadata -> Info about how data is stored in blocks
```

There are files that have names that look something like `bl*.meta` but I think they just contain the checksum information for the blocks and therefore may not be relevant here. Reference - [What metadata is stored on a datanode in HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25726452/4647107)

Where do the datanodes store the file -> block mapping?

Since there could be multiple datanodes with file data split across them, how do I get this information from the NameNode's FSImage/edit logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the block information directly from the bl*.meta.  This information is sent to the NameNode when a Datanode comes online.  The information is in the meta files but really the position on the disks itself is what is used to generate the meta files [when a node starts (implied by hadoop 2.6 manual balancing of disks)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1312).

You may find it helpful to study some of the github projects that are created to balance datanode disks as it [requires knowledge of metadata](https://github.com/schmmd/hadoop-balancer/blob/main/src/main/scala/com/schmitztech/hadoop/DataDirectory.scala).

You may want to look at some of the [github tools availble for analyzing FSImage](https://github.com/search?q=FSImage). Which may help you find the information you are looking for.